# How to get Plone's CSS Registry to load new CSS files

Tags: plone

I'm trying to upgrade a Plone 3.3.5 server to 4.3.6. However, when I update the site, I find that the CSS for the site is not carried over. If I go to my CSS Registry, I find that almost all of my CSS is producing the `(resource not found or not accessible)` error.

My confusion seems to be in how Plone locates and links/imports stylesheets in general as Plone seems to be loading virtually none of my CSS and pretty much giving me raw HTML in the browser. I'm assuming the CSS registry is loading CSS from the buildout-cache. With this assumption, an example stylesheet that I'm targeting is located under:

```
Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.NuPlone-1.0b3-py2.7.egg/Products/NuPlone/skins/nuplone_styles/base.css
```

When the CSS Registry failed to load this, I noticed that some CSS was being loaded in via handles like this:

```
++resource++tinymce.stylesheets/tinymce.css
```

But this format doesn't work with `base.css` and others.

So my question is, given I've got a new product installed with some CSS included in it, how do I get Plone to target said CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For resources inside "skins" FS folders, the way to register on `portal_css` tool is to simply provide the filename, so simply put there `base.css`.

If this is not working probably the `nuplone_styles` skin folder is not registered properly in the `portal_skins` tool.

So go to ZMI --> portal_skins --> click on "Properties" and check the following:

- what theme is used? You must probably switch back to NuPlone (but I'm not sure if it works on Plone 4)
- is the `nuplone_styles` folder in the list of CMF layers of the used theme?

Please note also that adding the `nuplone_styles` layer to another theme is not a good idea. Please think about copying CSS you need in the `custom` directory.

Comment: The best. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but some additional explanation, not fitting in a comment:

The "old" way to include style-sheets via skin-folders, requires to specify only the file-name, not a full path, and will be found by traversal, meaning the first found file with the according name, will be taken. In case of several files with the same name, the order of skins matters.

The other way is to register style-sheets via a browser-package, to have an unambiguous path to a certain file, they must start with `+++resource++`.